# How to rotate a Curve in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to rotate a `Curve` (especially a `EllipseCurve`) in Three.js. My app looks basically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w9914420/krw8nwLn/14/

But `EllipseCurve` can't be rotated at the Y-Axis. Is there a way to "transform" such 2D-curves to 3D-curves in Three.js? Three.js provides `CatmullRomCurve3`, `CubicBezierCurve3` and `LineCurve3` for 3D-curves, but I don't get a nice circle (or ellipse) with these methods – and I need something that is based on Three.js' `Curve` because I need the `getPoint` and `getTangent` methods.

**Edit**

OK, the problem isn't the curve path itself, it's the calculation of `getPoint`.

I've created an own version, but don't get the math the calculate the `z` axis right. Something like this works for the first few values of `this.rotation` (around -0.5 and 0.5 – higher values doesn't have the same effect in distance):

```
getPointOnCurve(t) {
  const radians = 2 * Math.PI * t

  return new THREE.Vector3(
    this.radius * Math.cos(radians),
    this.radius * Math.sin(radians),
    this.radius * Math.cos(radians) * this.rotation
  )
}
```

I need to know better about the math that's needed for this, definitely.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/66/) what you are trying to do?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks! :-) But now I have to fix the `up` vector, because the square itself rotates about his own flight axis.

Comment: OK, got it, `lookAt` does the trick :) http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/68/

Comment: @WestLangley I'm trying to create a camera that follows the cube, but it changes the direction on the polar coordinates of the ellipse – looks little bit weird: http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/69/ Do you know how to setup the camera that follows the object in an infinite way? I've created another example: the second cube should be the camera: http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/70/

Comment: Maybe the animation option in [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html) will help.

Comment: Aaah, great, thank you very much! :-)